# How to check if Excel Add-in is installed for Macintosh Users with VBA

Tags: vba, macos, excel

Using VBA, I am able to detect if a specific add-in is installed for Windows Microsoft Office - Excel, but the same code is unable to detect when executed in MacOS Microsoft Office - Excel.

Below is a sample of my code I try to execute in Microsoft Excel 2016 for Macintosh.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

rw = 0
flag = 0
If InStr(Application.OperatingSystem, "Macintosh") Then
For Each ad In Application.AddIns
    If flag > 0 Then
        Exit For
    Else
        If InStr(ad.Name, "Vena") Then
            MsgBox "Vena add-in is installed."
            flag = 1
        Else
            MsgBox "Vena add-in is not installed."
        End If
        rw = rw + 1
    End If
Next
Else
MsgBox "Vena is not compatible with your Operating System."
End If
End Sub
```

In the MacOS Microsoft Office environment, the Excel Add-in is installed.  However, when I execute the code, I am notified that the add-in is not installed. Screenshot of error message:

[image: img1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would give that message if you have any other add-in installed, since it shows the message for any add-in that doesn't have Vena in its name. I'd suggest something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

rw = 0
flag = 0
If InStr(Application.OperatingSystem, "Macintosh") Then
    For Each ad In Application.AddIns
        If InStr(1, ad.Name, "Vena", vbtextcompare) Then
            MsgBox "Vena add-in is installed."
            flag = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If flag = 0 then MsgBox "Vena add-in is not installed."
Else
    MsgBox "Vena is not compatible with your Operating System."
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you happen to know if there is a way for the Mac version of Excel to detect if an add-in is installed?